# Same taxonomy for different object types

Tags: custom-taxonomy, oop, terms

Starting with WP 2.3 we can do this:

```
register_taxonomy('custom_taxonomy', array('user', 'post', 'link', 'comment'));
```

Those are different object types that belong to different tables and hence can have same primary key ID. Now if we take a look at the functions used to get or check terms, they all lack object_type parameter.

```
is_object_in_term( $object_id, $taxonomy, $terms = null );
wp_get_object_terms( $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args );
```

As a matter of fact, there is no reference to object type in term_relationships table at all, and you are going to get false positives for objects with same IDs. How can one fix that?

Answer (score 1):

> Those are different object types that belong to different tables and hence can have same primary key ID.

--> Even though these are different types, all are being stored in one table i.e. `wp_posts` with `post_type` = the different types. Check the table structure for clarity. So there won't be any same ID conflict.

> if we take a look at the functions used to get or check terms, they all lack object_type parameter.

--> This is not needed. When we have the object itself, WordPress functions can better decide its associated type from the DB.

> As a matter of fact, there is no reference to object type in term_relationships table at all, and you are going to get false positives for objects with same IDs.

--> This is also wrong assumption. There is clear relationship between the tables need to manage the categorizations in WordPress. Here is a snap that explains relationships. [image]

Comment: I am not talking about post_types, I am talking about objects. User objects are stored in users table, links in links and comments in comments.

Comment: You are correct. I haven't dig that deep. Also not sure if the above functions take care of the object_types( user, comment, link ) into consideration. A quick look into the code shows that it doesn't consider these object types while fetching the terms. [https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2161](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2161)

Comment: You can check this tutorial by @JustinTadlock for some idea (may be it helps): [http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress)